# how to prevent asking for permission every time I insert SD card?

Tags: permissions, sd-card

These days for experiment, I frequently insert SD card into my ubuntu 20.04 machine and write data to a parition using `dd` command. But every time I insert SD card, the OS asks me to enter my password. How can I prevent this? (Maybe I can't, because there is no way the OS knows that it's me that's inserting the card..)

Comment: If you cd to the folder where the SD card is mounted the output of `ls -l`? You should be able to see the owner of the root of the SD card. If it’s not you that’s probably your problem. To fix try changing the owner. However your dd command may change it back. All this assumes a Linux filesystem on the SD card. If it’s something else the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @PonJar Hi, the partition doesn't contain any file system. I just write raw data to some predefined sections.

Comment: If there is no filesystem Ubuntu cannot know if you are authorised to use the device hence the password request. This is just a guess though, I’ve not done this myself. Do you have a reason for not using a filesystem. People get weird problems when they use devices without filesystems.

Comment: In our board,  my baremetal program reads the SD card's partition (by read MBR and detects the start of first partition), and read the predefined blocks and loads the data on RAM.  baremetal, so no file system. I think there is no way the OS can know the person who inserted the SD card is me.